# Multiply-defined labels warnings with frame labels in Beamer with againframe

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

This question is pretty much identical to [this (to the best of my knowledge) unanswered question from comp.text.tex](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-01/msg00317.html), which, at the moment, is the top Google hit for this problem: when specifying frame labels in Beamer with the intention of using them with the `\againframe` command, LaTeX begins spitting out errors over "multiply-defined labels".

Here's a specific, compilable example to demonstrate this issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=firstframe]{The first frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is not the fourth slide
            \pause
        \item Ah, but now it \emph{is} the fourth slide!
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The second frame}
    This is a boring second slide.
\end{frame}

\againframe{firstframe}

\end{document}
```

The intention here is to display the first frame's first bullet point in the first slide, then again on the third slide, and then both bullet points on the fourth slide.

LaTeX will report the following warnings when compiling this presentation:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `firstframe<1>' multiply defined.


LaTeX Warning: Label `firstframe' multiply defined.
```

How does one remove the occurrence of these warnings, other than avoiding the use of `\againframe`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You add a second `\pause` and use the overlay specification. Like this

```
\begin{frame}<1>[label=firstframe]{The first frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is not the fourth slide
            \pause \pause
        \item Ah, but now it \emph{is} the fourth slide!
    \end{itemize} \end{frame}

\begin{frame}{The second frame}
    This is a boring second slide. \end{frame}

\againframe<2-3>{firstframe}
```

Yes, the solution is a bit silly, but this has to do with how `beamer` process the `\againframe` command internally. The command is built to 'continue' a frame, not to 'repeat' a frame. (The reason that you get repeated label warnings is that every frame/overlay is labelled internally (so that the various TOC jumping around and hyperlinks work). If you label a frame, the internal labels will be `name<n>` for the n'th overlay of that frame.)

Answer (score 20):

Link Willie Wong said,

> The command is built to 'continue' a frame, not to 'repeat' a frame.

So the code:

```
\begin{frame}[label=firstframe]{The first frame}
   ....
\end{frame}
```

creates an element "firstframe<1>" and the code:

```
\againframe{firstframe}
```

creates also an element named "firstframe<1>" which is obviously not possible.

**The solution** is simple: change the overlay ID so that it will not conflict with existing overlays for this frame.

**Example:**

```
\begin{frame}[label=firstframe]{The first frame}
   ....
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{firstframe}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not break some things if you actually use labels in your slides, but if you only label the frame to use `\againframe`  then the following quick and dirty hack might do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{relabel}{%\def\beamer@againname{#1}%
  \def\beamer@undolabels{{\let\@elt\beamer@restorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=firstframe]
\frametitle{The first frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is not the fourth slide 
            \pause
        \item Ah, but now it \emph{is} the fourth slide!
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The second frame}
    This is a boring second slide.
\end{frame}

\againframe{firstframe}

\end{document}
```