# beamer: using \note<> and frame labels together creates multiply-defined labels

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

This question is very similar to  [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/multiply-defined-labels-warnings-with-frame-labels-in-beamer-with-againframe). However, since the solution provided there cannot solve my problem, I figured that I'd post my specific problem.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate this issue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2>[label=myframe]{Frame Title}
  \note<1>{Some notes on the first point.}
  \note<2>{Some notes on the second point.}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<alert@1> First point.
  \item<alert@2> Second point.
  \item<alert@3> Third point. %optional
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}{Appendix}
  Some more elaboration.
\end{frame}
\againframe<3>{myframe}
\end{document}
```

This example is compilable, but LaTeX tells me there are multiply defined labels. The labels in question are `myframe`, `myframe<1>` and `myframe<2>`. I *conjecture* this is due to the fact that when a note page is created, the note page also "inherits" the label of the main frame, thus creating such problem. If so, I guess we could somehow patch the note page mechanism in `beamer` such that LaTeX would stop emit such warnings.

Anyone has any solutions?

Comment: Just an observation rather than anything helpful: the `\againframe` does not appear to responsible for the duplicated labels here; commenting it out does not change the behaviour, but leaving it in and commenting out the `\setbeameroption{show notes}` removes the warnings.

Comment: @cyberSingularity That's right. Thanks for the observation. I have modified the title so that it doesn't mention `\againframe`. I always thought one main reason for using labels is to use `\againframe`.

Comment: Working intensely with beamer I have got so many "multiply defined labels" warnings that I somehow got used to them. I have, however, never experienced any particular problem with them as they tend to end up on the same page. So besides compiler output aesthetics: Is there a concrete issue?

Comment: As far as I understand, this is not really as simple as being a bug in `beamer`. I will attempt to explain more later, showing the results of my diagnosis, and hopefully offer a potential fix, or at least the beginnings of one. (Please don't close the question in the meantime!) @Daniel: Multiply defined labels can be an issue, depending on how you are later referring to those labels. Again, I'll try to explain more later.

Comment: @Daniel: If you are used to all kind of warnings in beamer, I suspect http://texblog.net/latex-archive/presentations/beamer-warnings/ could help. Regarding your specific problem, I cannot help :-(

Comment: Besides the TeXnical issues: How do you intent to use your notes in the end? If you are basically printing them out on paper I could suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: @Daniel Most likely I'm going to use them in the slides, using `\setbeameroption{show notes}` or `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}` depending on the situation. I guess if I were to print out the notes, compiling two versions of documents, one with only notes the other with only slides would be a good idea. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: Well, I am mostly printing them out on paper. For this, I compile only a single version of the document, but apply [this trick](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11708/run-macro-on-each-frame-in-beamer) to ensure that _every_ slide is followed by a notes page (containing text only). I then pipe the resulting PDF through `pdfnup --nup 1x2` to get A4 pages with the slide on the top and the notes on the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Understanding why the problem occurs and how to potentially fix it is a bit TeXnical I'm afraid.

### Diagnosing causes of the problem:

- Disabling notes eliminates the issue.
- Redefining `\insertslideintonotes` to do nothing eliminates the issue: `\renewcommand{\insertslideintonotes}[1]{}`.
- Using any form of `\label` (even `\label<1>`) in a slide with notes causes the issue, not just using the `label=name` option to frames (the latter internally uses `\label` anyway).
- **Implementation of `\insertslideintonotes` in beamer:**

  `beamer` puts the contents of each slide into a box register called `\beamer@framebox`, and copies the box register into `\beamer@frameboxcopy`. The latter is used for the mini version of the slide shown in the notes pages (via `\insertslideintonotes`). Label commands are also stored in those boxes in the form of 'whatsit' `\write` nodes, and so are written again when the box is copied.

### Why multiply defined labels can be problematic:

- Multiply defined labels are not always consistent. The default behaviour in LaTeX is to use the **last** defined label, rather than ignoring later redefinitions of the same label. This is not the desired behaviour in the case of `beamer` because the label will then refer to notes slides instead of the main slide (as notes slides always come after the main slide). The following example illustrates this (the reference in the last frame is wrong):

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \setbeameroption{show notes}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<1-2>[label=myframe]{Frame Title}
    \note<1>{Some notes on the first point.}
    \note<2>{Some notes on the second point.}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<alert@1> First point.
    \item<alert@2> Second point.
    \item<alert@3> Third point. %optional
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
  \appendix
  \begin{frame}{Appendix}
    Some more elaboration.

    I think \texttt{myframe} starts on page \getpagerefnumber{myframe}.
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

### Solutions

- I asked a question about removing or deactivating such nodes in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82250/17427), and Stephan Lehmke's solution led me to the following patch. The idea is that by editing the box to use `\leaders`, TeX will ignore the `\write` whatsits. I will try to get the `beamer` maintainers to consider it for inclusion in the `beamer` core:

  Patch code:

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  \patchcmd\beamer@framenotesend{\global\setbox\beamer@frameboxcopy=\copy\beamer@framebox}{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@frameboxcopy=\copy\beamer@framebox
  \global\setbox\beamer@frameboxcopy=\hbox{\leaders\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy\hskip\wd\beamer@frameboxcopy}%from Stephan Lehmke's comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82250/17427
  }{}{\showtokens{failed to patch \beamer@framenotesend}}
  \makeatother
  ```

  Patched MWE (note that the `pdfTeX warning (dest)` messages are another [outstanding issue in beamer](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/147)):

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \setbeameroption{show notes}

  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \makeatletter
  \patchcmd\beamer@framenotesend{\global\setbox\beamer@frameboxcopy=\copy\beamer@framebox}{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@frameboxcopy=\copy\beamer@framebox
  \global\setbox\beamer@frameboxcopy=\hbox{\leaders\copy\beamer@frameboxcopy\hskip\wd\beamer@frameboxcopy}%from Stephan Lehmke's comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82250/17427
  }{}{\showtokens{failed to patch \beamer@framenotesend}}
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<1-2>[label=myframe]{Frame Title}
    \note<1>{Some notes on the first point.}
    \note<2>{Some notes on the second point.}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<alert@1> First point.
    \item<alert@2> Second point.
    \item<alert@3> Third point. %optional
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
  \appendix
  \begin{frame}{Appendix}
    Some more elaboration.

    I think \texttt{myframe} starts on page \getpagerefnumber{myframe}.
  \end{frame}
  \againframe<3>{myframe}
  \end{document}
  ```
- The alternative implementation that `beamer` could take would be to reprocess the content of the whole frame again when calling `\insertslideintonotes`, but which might have other unwanted side-effects in some circumstances, and so this should only be provided as an option to people who know what they are doing, instead of changing default behaviour! I don't think this would be an easy job either.
- You could also use the following patch in the preamble to only save the first `\label`, and hope everything will be alright.

  ```
  % keep only the first definition of a given label, in contrast to the default LaTeX behaviour (and compile twice to see the difference!)
  \makeatletter
  \def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{%
    \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
      {\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}% moved this line from always being executed into the 'true' case for \@ifundefined.
      {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
         \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels. Later redefinitions were ignored}}%
       \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#2' multiply defined. Ignoring later redefinitions}}%
    }}
  \makeatother
  ```

Comment: Now reported at https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issue/226/using-labels-and-notes-causes-multiply

Comment: ...and already fixed using the `\leaders` suggestion, should be included in the next `beamer` release.